# How can I use proc sql to delete all rows of specific IDs according to a specific value of another variable?

Tags: sql, sas

For example, I want to delete all rows of a specific ID, if the ID has Op=1 in any observation.

I want to change the following dataset (Data1) to Data2.

Example:

[image: Example]

I have used only SAS EG version for my tasks, and this process could not be done for myself. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It would be better to have these data as pre formated text. When the data is sorted by ID it is very easy to do with normal datastep.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. This is my first time to ask a question in this web site, and I really astonished at your prompt and clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem first use an data step. That works by merging the table with itself but the second time only with the rows you don't want. Keep only those rows id that are not in the subset.

```
data data2;
  merge data1 data1(keep=id op where=(_op=1) rename=(op=_op) in=i);
  by id;
  if ^i;
  drop _op;
run;
```

The other one is by using sql to create a new dataset with an id that is not in the subset generated similar to approach one.

```
proc sql;
  create table data2 as select * from data1 where id not in(select id from data1 where op=1);
quit;
```